# Issue with solr-jetty with a fresh re-installation of CKAN, Jetty and Solr

Tags: solr, jetty, ubuntu-14.04, ckan

I am trying to install CKAN on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, but I ran into some errors that I can't fix.

I tried to do a fresh installation after I removed everything from my computer. I am getting some errors. When I try to run:
`sudo apt-get remove jetty`, I get:

> *Stopping Jetty servlet engine (was reachable on
>   http://myComputer-ubuntu:8983/).
>
> jetty start-stop-daemon: user 'solr' not found
>
> start-stop-daemon: user 'solr' not found
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript jetty, action "stop" failed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package jetty (--remove):  subprocess installed
>   pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
>
> *Starting Jetty servlet engine. jetty start-stop-daemon: user 'solr'
>   not found  *(already running).
>                                            [ OK ]
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> jetty
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit:

After trying `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove jetty`
I get this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   jetty : Depends:
>   libjetty-java (>= 6.1.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not installed
>
> Depends: jsvc but it is not installed
>
> Depends: apache2-utils
>   How on earth can i completely remove Jetty!!??!!

Edit2:

When trying `sudo apt-get remove jetty`:

I get a message saying jetty is not installed, but at the same time it is giving my an error that jetty's dependencies are not met!

Comment: I'm having this exact issue (while trying to install CKAN on Ubuntu etc...). Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I just found that there is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jetty/+bug/1021193. Advise you follow that link, sign up to Ubuntu One (if you haven't already), and vote for it if this is affecting you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same error messages on Ubuntu 14 and I've just figured out what it was.

The issue was with the line endings of `/etc/default/jetty`. It turned out that the file had been edited on Windows and had line endings of `CRLF`, once I updated the file to `LF` and re-ran it the issue was solved.

The quickest way to test this is to revert back to Jetty's original config by running `sudo mv /etc/default/jetty /tmp/` and then run `sudo service jetty restart`. If you have the same issue as me, jetty will restart properly.